# Create gradle task that doesn't load any configuration

Tags: gradle

I want to create a gradle task that doesn't load **any** other configuration. I know about the configuration avoidance API and that's not what I'm looking for. I want to have a small task akin to a custom script and I **know** that task won't depend on anything else, no included projects etc. I just want to avoid having the whole gradle configuration phase load all the things before running something that takes < 100ms. Is that possible or do I have to refactor my whole gradle project to use lazy configuration just for this?

Some code for context:

```
task preBuildStuff {
  // slow configuration
}

task changePropertyValue {
  // quick file write
  // doesn't depend on anything else, in this or included builds, just a small script
}
```

Yes I know this could just be a distinct python or even groovy script but I want to have it in gradle because it is also used during the general build and for grouping purposes as well.

Note that it must also avoid plugin configurations! Plugins are a major bottleneck as well it seems.